# sqlalchemy engine.connect() and engine.begin() against auto commit

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

from this document [sqlalchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/dbapi_transactions.html) I can understand that `engine.connect` will not commit changes automatically unless the `conn.commit()` is called explicit.While `engine.begin()` will take care of all transactional events.

However when I tried on my own with local MySQL. I found that the code ran differently as the document said.

insert with connect:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

with mysql_engine.connect() as conn:
    create_stat = "create table if not exists test.test_commit (x int, y int)"
    conn.execute(create_stat)

with mysql_engine.connect() as conn:
    insert_stat = "insert into test.test_commit(x, y) VALUES(1, 2)"
    conn.execute(insert_stat)

with mysql_engine.connect() as conn:
    select_stat = "select * from test.test_commit;"
    res = conn.execute(select_stat)
    print(res.all())
```

Above codes return the inserted data. But I did not call commit. I tried to call `conn.commit()`, while I got an attribute error said that `'Connection' object has no attribute 'commit'`

I am using sqlalchemy 1.4.13.

please tell me why I got different results against the official document ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using SQLAlchemy 1.4 but reading the tutorial for SQLAlchemy 2.0. The 1.4 docs are [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/index.html). If you want 2.0 behaviour in 1.4 you must pass `future=True` to `create_engine`.

Note that if you do pass `future=True`, you must wrap all raw SQL statements with the `text` function:

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(text("""INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2) VALUES (1, 2)"""))
```

Comment: yes, previously I thougth the behaviour maybe the same with in 1.x and 2.x. Now I updated the package to 2.x and it works as the document said. Thanks a lot!